# Find with Regular Expression, with exception

Tags: regex

I have to find with exception something like this:

find: dt

Expected Results:  dt, blabladtblabla ...

Except:  width

In other words, I need to find all strings with "dt" chars, except if string is "width"

- I'm using TextCrawler / English to find and replace strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular expression implementations that support look-behinds you could use

```
(?<!wi)dt|dt(?!h)
```

In javascript you could hack up something like

```
/^.?dt|(?!width)..dt/m.test( '  width' );    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

[look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex

See this [TextCrawler forum post](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/board/viewtopic.php?p=2401#p2401)

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe something like this:


 /^(?!wi)dt|dt(?!h)/g;
```

Comment: This needs improvement: Your first negative look-ahead should be a look-behind and the caret should be removed.

Comment: This was just a quicky. I ran a few tests and it passed.. but you are probably right. I didn't run it thru alot of tests, just a few. off to the beach, if this hasn't been answered, i'll redo it. I am still learning.